# How to align select and select box while select's position changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a fun problem with the native html select element.
when you click the select, after it the select's position change, but the box under the select won't change it's position to align with it.

[image]

Here is a simple code sample.

```js
(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('span').innerText = "Test of metal";
  }, 3000)
})()
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="span"></span>
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

how to make the box align with the select itself? Is there any solution?

Comment: You can do a custom select with js/css

Comment: You need move your list by js

Comment: what you are having is sometthing good because when the text change the cursor is not changing so as a user I don't want to lose my navigation on the select element

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    (() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('span').innerText = "Test of metal",
    document.getElementById('select_id');
  }, 3000)
  
})()
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="span"></span>
  <select id="select_id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

change the `3000` value to faster the text shows up

Comment: can you tell us the difference between your code and his code? the same thing is happening

Comment: the difference are, I make an id for the select tag and I move the same distance as the span tag